# How to get the last document in a documentdb collection with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I want to get the last document in een documentdb collection. But i have 2 problems.

**First problem** is when i create documents in a loop, it does not create documents in same order and therefore the last document in the database is not the last element in the array. I fixed that with `slice()` function. I take out the last element of the array and create a document apart with `setTimeout()` function. It works but is there any better way for this?

**Second problem** is querying in database. I do not want to query all documents in the database. Therefore i want to use `LAST()` SQL function, but it gives error **'LAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.**. I can use this statement well.

```
SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC;
```

But is that useful to query all documents? I mean if there are 10.000 documents or more is that a good way? Or is there any way to get the last document without querying all documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: There's really no concept of a *last* document. If you add an `ORDER BY` on your query, then you can fetch the `TOP N` as you posted in your 2nd example. Without a sort order, there's no concept of "last" (or even "first" for that matter - `TOP 1` on an unordered query could theoretically return *any* document - you'd just skim off the first one in the result set).

As for querying all documents: You're *not* querying all documents. Since, by default, all properties are indexed, you're just getting the first document based on the `CustomerID` property sort order. There's no reason for the database engine to do a collection-scan for this type of query.